# IE(Internet Explorer) - open dropdownlist and select one option with C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automatize a process that some of my colleague are doing.
I'm trying to build an C# WindowsFormApp to do that, but I've encounter a problem.
When i'm trying to select an option from a dropdownlist it doesn't open, in order to let me select one of the option.
Here it's the IE code:

```
<select name="rptreports$ctl00$ctl09$ddValue" id="rptreports_ctl00_ctl09_ddValue" style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana"   onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'rptreports$ctl00$ctl09$ddValue\',\'\')', 0)">
<option value="0"><Select a Value></option>
<option value="1">Hertz</option>
</select>
```

and this is the how i'm trying to access it with c#:

```
var doc2 = IE.Document;
var dropdownlist1 = doc2.GetElementById("rptreports_ctl00_ctl09_ddValue");
dropdownlist1.click();
```

I'll appreciate any help, Thanks

Comment: You don't need to open to select value just set selected value or set the required option selected

Comment: `SetAttribute` directly